# Tablesorter example not working

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

This should work:

```
<head>
    <title>Damn</title>
    <script src="jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter();
    }); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Difference</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>

            <td>Parker</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>$9.99</td>
            <td>20.9%</td>
            <td>+12.1</td>
            <td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Hood</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>$19.99</td>
            <td>25%</td>

            <td>+12</td>
            <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Clark</td>
            <td>Kent</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>$15.89</td>
            <td>44%</td>
            <td>-26</td>
            <td>Jan 12, 2003 11:14 AM</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

But it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?
NOTE: I don't understand much, but this seems to follow the example on the home page of Tablesorter without errors.
And I know I'll be completely ashamed.

Comment: Use firebug (firefox plugin) to determine if there are any script errors on your page preventing the tablesorter from firing.  Let us know if this turns up any errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have included the necessary files in the appropriate location?

Answer (score 7):

close your script tag properly

```
<script src="jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you have to close it with `</script>`

Comment: +1 for this. You can't close your script tags with self-closing tag, or they won't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this and it worked fine except that I had to put the full path to the table sortet script files because I don't have them.

```
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

do these 2 actually point to existing files?

```
<script src="jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```