# Jquery basic Table Sorter not working

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter

This is really basic table sorting code...
Does this work for you ? I can't figure why it's not working on my machine (Chrome or IE).
I took that from [Tablesorter example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667025/tablesorter-example-not-working)
but I did close my "script" tag though.

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript">                

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter();
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Difference</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>

        <td>Parker</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>$9.99</td>
        <td>20.9%</td>
        <td>+12.1</td>
        <td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Hood</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>$19.99</td>
        <td>25%</td>

        <td>+12</td>
        <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>Kent</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>$15.89</td>
        <td>44%</td>
        <td>-26</td>
        <td>Jan 12, 2003 11:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download table sorter plugin and add reference to your project..  it may work perfect..

Comment: ok that's fixed http://tablesorter.com/jquery.tablesorter.min.js
sends back a 404 error -_-